# How to create staging server in AWS? Already have a running website on it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to create staging server. Any help would be much appreciated.

I already have a running website on it.

Comment: Could you please Edit your question and provide more information? For example, how do you define "staging server"? How will you configure the staging server -- can you reinstall everything, or do you wish to create an exact copy of an existing Amazon EC2 server? Does your system store information in a database and, if so, is the database on the same server? Do you wish to regularly updating your staging server from production? Please tell us more so we can assist you.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using AWS Ec2 to run your website, you can take a snapshot, create an AMI and use the AMI to launch a new server.

Rough steps would be;-

### To create a snapshot using the console

- Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/
- Choose Snapshots in the navigation
- Choose Create
- In the Create Snapshot dialog box, select the volume to create a
  snapshot for, and then choose Create.

### Create an AMI

- In the navigation pane, under Elastic Block Store, choose Snapshots.
- Choose the snapshot and choose Actions, Create Image.
- In the Create Image from EBS Snapshot dialog box, complete the fields to create your AMI, then choose Create. If you're re-creating a parent instance, then choose the same options as the parent instance.

  - Architecture: Choose i386 for 32-bit or x86_64 for 64-bit.
    Root device name: Enter the appropriate name for the root volume. For more information, see Device Naming on Linux Instances.
  - Virtualization type: Choose whether instances launched from this AMI use paravirtual (PV) or hardware virtual machine (HVM) virtualization. For more information, see Linux AMI Virtualization Types.
  - (PV virtualization type only) Kernel ID and RAM disk ID: Choose the AKI and ARI from the lists. If you choose the default AKI or don't choose an AKI, you'll be required to specify an AKI every time you launch an instance using this AMI. In addition, your instance may fail the health checks if the default AKI is incompatible with the instance.
  - (Optional) Block Device Mappings: Add volumes or expand the default size of the root volume for the AMI. For more information about resizing the file system on your instance for a larger volume, see Extending a Linux File System after Resizing the Volume.

## Launch your new staging EC2 instance from the AMI you created in the previous step;

- From the left navigation bar, choose AMIs.
- Find the AMI you want to use to launch a new instance. To begin, open the menu next to the search bar and choose one of the following:
- Select Owned by me.
- Select the AMI and choose Launch.
- The console will guide you through the rest of configuration of your instance.
- Choose Review and Launch when you are satisfied with your settings.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is through the web management console:

go to the instance 
select the instance and click on instance action create image

Once you have an image you can launch another cloned instance, data and all. :)

Refer this [creating image](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html)